# Как генерировать ссылки с https в Symfony 3?

Tags: php, https, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Что и где нужно прописать чтоб Symfony 3 генерировала ссылки по умолчанию с https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы используете `{{ path('your_route') }}` в шаблонах, то проблем не будет, т.к он генерит относительный пути. Вам лишь нужно лишь при заходе на сайт перекинуть на https, используя .htaccess.